# Limit of $\frac{\exp(z)-1}{z}$ for $z \rightarrow 0$

Tags: limits

I would like to show that the limit of $\frac{\exp(z)-1}{z}$ for $z \rightarrow 0$ is $1$. But I don't know how to use the definition of $\exp(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Why use the definition? This is just an application of LH rule, $exp(z)=e^z$

Comment: @KSplitX Invoking LH to compute a limit $\lim(f(z)-f(0))/(z-0)$ is always illogical and a bad idea.

Comment: @Did Not at all. For instance, proving the statement “if $f$ is continuous at $a$, differentiable in a punctured neighborhood of $a$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)=c$ then $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f'(a)=c$” consists exactly in applying LH in the situation you mention.

Comment: @egreg To compute the limit using L'H, one should check every hypothesis necessary to LH to apply. Amongst these hypotheses is the existence of the limit itself... (If I may add, this point has been discussed to death on the site, multiple times.)

Comment: @Did The existence of the limit of the quotient of the derivatives! Which is among the assumptions of the statement: did you read them? Since the denominator in this case is $x-a$, the hypotheses of LH clearly are satisfied. This is a perfectly legal and good application of LH; your “always” should be changed into “often”. Of course the particular case in the present question does not belong to the cases where LH is good.

Comment: @egreg "Of course the particular case in the present question does not belong to the cases where LH is good" Indeed, because it corresponds to the function $g(z)=z$ in the denominator, **which is precisely the point of my first comment**. Hence: "always". ("did you read them?"Sure you do not regret to have written this, now?)

Comment: @Did OK, you don't want to listen to different opinions. Anyway, there is plenty of functions where the simplest technique for computing a derivative with the theorem is useful. A trivial one is $f(x)=x|x|$, which of course can be dealt with via the definition, but shows the point.

Comment: @egreg Sorry but I had the impression that I had taken care of describing **precisely** why my first comment was **trivially true**. In my world, this is called "listening", in the full sense of the term (and yes, it requires to have read very carefully what is written by others...).

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

$$\exp(z)=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

Comment: gimusi: Sorry, this not right in the context of question, but how you manage to get 380 points a day since there is reputation cap at 200 points?

Comment: I didn’t know of the cap!

Comment: @ChristianF I've verified better the issue, the fact is simple: the cap is valid for the upvotes but not for the accepted answer. Yesterday a had more than 20 upvotes and 12 accepted answers that is 200+12*15=380.

Answer (score 0):

$ \left | \frac{\exp(z)-1}{z}-1 \right | =\left| \frac{1}{z} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}-1 \right |= \left | \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{(n+1)!}-1\right|= \left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{(n+1)!} \right|= \vert z \vert \left| \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{(n+2)!}\right| ≤\vert z \vert \cdot e $

therefore you get then $\lim_{z \rightarrow0} \left|\frac{\exp(z)-1}{z}-1  \right|=0 \Longrightarrow \lim_{z \rightarrow0} \left|\frac{\exp(z)-1 }{z}  \right|=1$